# Build flavour for non-telephony devices

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-build, android-build-type, android-build-flavors

I'm working on an app that can make calls and thus requires telephony permissions, but also has other options if telephony isn't available (for example, a hand scanner that runs Android).

Am I able to make a build flavour for devices without telephony (so that I can remove the permission)?

My goal here is to have both telephony and non-telephony devices see my app on Google Play and both be able to download and use it seamlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found this: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Which says: "you cannot provide different APKs that differ purely on the 'uses-configuration' characteristics", which basically answers my question :(